# jQWidgets: Is there a place where i can find a structured list of used properties?

Tags: jquery, reserved-words, jqwidget

I don't really know how this question fits or not to the site, don't hesitate to comment if not (will be more useful than a bare downvote).

I am actually working on the minification of a JS core file, for a project that uses jQWidgets. The thing is that i have external parts of code (to the file) that can call jQWidgets functions or properties. They get mangled in the minification process, which breaks some external code.

So far, i have been adding them to an array for reserved keywords that the minifier uses. Its structure is very simple, ex:

```
reserved: ['noConflict', 'holdReady', 'fn', 'isFunction', ...]
```

The fact is that the process is long, there are lots of keywords, and so far it does not cope with evolution of the code that may add other properties not listed.

**Is there someone that already listed these properties, either in a code array (whatever the language), or in a list from which i can extract easily? Or maybe a script that works directly with the Widgets code?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the  [jQWidgets TypeScript definitions](https://github.com/jqwidgets/jQWidgets/blob/master/jqwidgets-ts/jqwidgets.d.ts) and extract the method´s names. I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the idea, didn't have the time to answer my own question, it seems that it will be simpler to extract them from the API web pages with a regex, as every property or function can be found in an html comment: `<!--propertyName-->`